# What is the difference between nodes and terminals?

Tags: terminology, terminal

So my textbook uses both of these terms but doesn't really give clear definition of each which is starting to lead to some minor confusion. I was reading a Wiki entry on ports which stated

> A port consists of two nodes (terminals) connected to an outside circuit...

But this sort of confuses me because to me that is saying that each terminal is its own node.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRLWsA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this random example (I've encountered this when shorting the circuit between terminal a and b in problems) wouldn't these two terminal share the same node? How could they be separate nodes? Any type of clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node is a point at which two or more circuit elements meet (e.g. a resistor and a voltage source). Wikipedia's article on a [circuit node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(circuits)) includes a drawing which highlights each node in an example circuit in a different color:

[image: nodes]

A terminal is a connection point to an external circuit. A terminal is usually a type of node, though by shorting two terminals they become a single node. If you connected a resistor between the two nodes instead of shorting them with an ideal wire then each terminal would also be a separate node.

Answer (score 3):

A terminal is part of a component. A node is a part of a circuit.

Terminals are the wires that let you connect to a component. For example, a resistor has two terminals. A BJT has three terminals, etc.

A node is all the wires in a circuit that are connected together by a low enough resistance that we can ignore it.

So you might connect a terminal of a part to a node in a circuit (which is also connected to other terminals of other parts). You might even connect multiple terminals of the same part to the same node of a circuit (like in a diode-connected transistor).